# Pyspark: unable to connect to Cloud SQL database

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I am trying to connect to Cloud SQL Postgres DB instance locally from a pyspark application via Cloud SQL Proxy.
I use this code:

```
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:postgresql://{options.get('PostgresHost')}:3307/mydb?user=myuser&password=password"
jdbc_properties = dict(
    user=options.get('postgresUsername'),
    password=options.get('postgresPassword'),
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
)
spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table="mytable", properties=jdbc_properties)
```

where PostgresHost is public IP of the DB.

I've:

- added my public IP to authorized networks in Cloud SQL connections
- added Cloud firewall rules for tcp connections on ports 3307, 5432
- disabled own firewall
- verified installed spark libs and drivers by trying to connect to local Postgres DB (successfully)

Nothing seems to work so far. Glad to hear your thoughts.

The error I get:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.jdbc.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:443)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:505)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    ... 25 more

python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the value of `{options.get('PostgresHost')}`? Take note that Cloud SQL Proxy listens to `127.0.0.1:PORT`

Comment: It's public IP of the DB

Comment: You mentioned that you've added your local IP to authorized networks of your Cloud SQL instance. You should use your [public ip](https://www.whatismyip.com/) instead.

Comment: Though since you are trying to connect via Cloud SQL proxy, then you really should follow the instructions on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy)

Comment: Instructions worked on my local machine with URL like /cloudsql/<db_conn_name>. The issue arises when connection to Cloud SQL DB's public IP
PS. Sorry, I meant my public IP, updated the question.

Comment: Then you are trying to connect using the public IP, not the proxy. Double check your port. The default port when connecting to a Postgres instance is `5432`.